# axis of rotation and rotation matrix

Tags: ios, rotation, core-motion

I am trying to find the axis of rotation for iphone.  Here is my approach:

step 1:  obtain rotation matrix - cur_rotM

step 2:  check if the rotation matrix differs from the prv_rotM; if pre_rotM doesn't exist, it skips the loop and assigns value of cur_rotM to pre_rotM.  At this point, I am simply comparing (subtracting) all the elements of the rotation matrices to see if there is a significant difference.

step 3:  if there is a significant different in cur_rotM and prv_rotM, I calculate a rotation matrix using this formula:
r = prv_rotM * transpose (cur_rotM)

step 4:  axis of rotation: {r32-r23, r13-r31, r21-r12}; I also calculated the angle of rotation by using atan2(x,y) where x is the magnitude of rotation matrix and y is (r11 + r22 + r33 - 1)..

step 5:  assing cur_rotM to prv_rotM and repeat the cycle

I am programming on iOS platform using core motion framework and using an iPhone device and using reference frame XTrueNorthZVertical.  My questions are:

the axis of rotation - what are those numbers - if I rotate the phone on a horizontal surface, all the numbers are close to zero.  When I rotate around the device on any other axis, I still see very small numbers and they keep changing, even though I may be rotating around the same axis.

I am doing this at 1/60 frequency and my filter for meaningful change in rotation matrix require that the device be moved fast.  So, I get several readings during one arc movement - which should all show the same axis - but that is not what I am seeing.

Is there a unit?  If I were to takt two axis vectors and find the shortest distance between them, what would be the unit of the measurement?

Let me know if this question makes sense or need clarity.

Many thanks,
A

Comment: I did not check whether your formulas are correct or not. Let's assume they are. If you don't like that the numbers for the axis are small, you can always normalize it to be the unit vector (divide each coordinate by the length of the entire vector, watch out for division by zero). The angles are supposedly in radian.

Comment: Thanks Ali. I am more concerned about what those numbers mean and what are the units?  As for the formula, they were suggested by you in previous question that I had asked a couple of months ago and I think the angle of rotation looks reasonably accurate.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I did not remember... The axis coordinates don't have units, that's why I suggested to normalize it to a unit vector in my previous comment. You can change the length of the axis as much as you like; only the direction matters. Glad to hear the angle is accurate.